# Wijmo 5 FlexGrid & AngularJS with Hierarchy and Pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, hierarchy, wijmo, c1flexgrid

I have a FlexGrid with hierarchy.  *(Examples below are edited for simplicity)*

My JSON looks like:

```
{ 'companies': [
    {
        'companyId': 1,
        'companyName': 'My Parent Company',
        'children': [
            { 'companyName': 'my first child company' },
            { 'companyName': 'my second child company' }
        ]
    },
    {
        'companyId': 2,
        'companyName': 'My Second Parent Company',
        'children': [
            { 'companyName': 'my first child company' },
            { 'companyName': 'my second child company' },
            { 'companyName': 'my third child company' }
        ]
    }]
}
```

My items-source is set to the top-level 'companies' array.
My child-items-path is set to the 'children' array for each parent element.

```
items-source="companies"
child-items-path="children"
```

It seems that the collectionView doesn't take the "children" into account during pagination.

It DOES sees the parents.

Please let me know if you need more information.
Any recommendations are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the design behavior. When you use the "childItemsPath" property, all collection operations are performed only for the top-level items (that includes sort, filter, and pagination).

The only suggestion that comes to my mind would be to not use pagination. Unless you have several hundreds of thousands of items, the grid should be able to display and manage all the items at once without any issues.

Comment: We ended up simply not using the childItemsPath property at all and simply simulated the hierarchy behavior manually.  It does the trick well enough.  I hope you guys can perhaps add pagination support for childItemsPath sometime.  Thanks for the help.